# Debian 8 hibernate and suspend not working

Tags: debian, power-management, suspend, hibernate

I've read these two official documentations on the matter:

- [Suspend and hibernate configuration in Debian Jessie](https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation#Suspend_and_hibernate_configuration_in_Debian_Jessie)
- [SystemdSuspendSedation](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemdSuspendSedation)

I've tried to make this simple script to see if anything is working:

I've installed all the packages they mention in the post.

```
# /etc/pm/sleep.d/suspend.sh
#
# The /etc/pm/sleep.d is the right place to put your custom suspend/resume scripts.
# None of the stuff in /etc/hibernate/ has _any_ effect (OnResume, RestartServices,
# UnloadModules etc). The /etc/init.d/atheros script is just a simple wrapper for
# unloading the ath_pci module.

case "$1" in
        hibernate|suspend)
        logger went to hibernate or suspend!
                ;;
        thaw|resume)
        logger resumed from hibernation or suspend!
                ;;
        *) exit $NA
                ;;
esac
```

No logger outputs.

so then I edited this file: `/etc/acpi/lid.sh`

and added this code

```
grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
  rfkill block all && hibernate -k -f
else
  rfkill unblock all
fi
```

If I try the suspend button that seems to work, the laptop goes to sleep and wakes up after a little while if I press the power button. Checking the logs I see these messages dealing with suspend.

```
Dec 14 00:25:16 host systemd[1]: Configuration file /etc/systemd/system/suspend-sedation.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Dec 14 00:25:16 host systemd[1]: Configuration file /etc/systemd/system/suspend-sedation.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Dec 14 00:25:35 host systemd[1]: Configuration file /etc/systemd/system/suspend-sedation.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Dec 14 00:25:35 host systemd[1]: Configuration file /etc/systemd/system/suspend-sedation.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Dec 14 00:30:22 host systemd[1]: Configuration file /etc/systemd/system/suspend-sedation.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Dec 14 00:30:22 host systemd[1]: Configuration file /etc/systemd/system/suspend-sedation.service is marked world-writable. Please remove world writability permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Dec 14 00:30:22 host systemd[1]: Configuration file /etc/systemd/system/suspend-sedation.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Dec 14 00:30:22 host systemd[1]: Configuration file /etc/systemd/system/suspend-sedation.service is marked world-writable. Please remove world writability permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Dec 14 00:31:43 host systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/suspend-sedation.service:1] Missing '='.
Dec 14 00:31:48 host systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/suspend-sedation.service:1] Missing '='.
Dec 14 00:32:11 host systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/suspend-sedation.service:1] Unknown section 'unit'. Ignoring.
Dec 14 00:33:07 host systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/suspend-sedation.service:1] Unknown section 'unit'. Ignoring.
Dec 14 00:36:26 host swapon[571]: swapon: /dev/sda4: software suspend data detected. Rewriting the swap signature.
Dec 14 00:36:26 host rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Mon Dec 14 00:36:56 2015 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Dec 14 00:41:38 host swapon[588]: swapon: /dev/sda4: software suspend data detected. Rewriting the swap signature.
Dec 14 00:41:38 host rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Mon Dec 14 00:42:08 2015 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Dec 14 00:54:53 host swapon[561]: swapon: /dev/sda4: software suspend data detected. Rewriting the swap signature.
Dec 14 00:54:53 host rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Mon Dec 14 00:55:23 2015 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Dec 14 01:05:22 host swapon[527]: swapon: /dev/sda4: software suspend data detected. Rewriting the swap signature.
Dec 14 01:05:22 host rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Mon Dec 14 01:05:52 2015 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Dec 14 01:09:21 host kernel: [  186.002598] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Dec 14 01:09:21 host kernel: [  186.046622] wl_suspend: PCI Suspend handler
Dec 14 01:09:21 host kernel: [  186.046631] wl_suspend: Not WOWL capable
Dec 14 01:09:21 host kernel: [  186.641662] PM: suspend of devices complete after 639.250 msecs
Dec 14 01:09:21 host kernel: [  186.642043] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.379 msecs
Dec 14 01:09:21 host kernel: [  186.657547] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 15.511 msecs


[  186.046622] wl_suspend: PCI Suspend handler
[  186.046631] wl_suspend: Not WOWL capable
[  186.641662] PM: suspend of devices complete after 639.250 msecs
[  186.642043] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.379 msecs
[  186.657547] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 15.511 msecs
```

now on to hibernate, that seems to just plain out die. It doesn't save state and everything I get sent all the way back to the EFI menu to chooser.

```
blubee@host:~$ sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep "hiber"
Dec 14 00:36:26 host kernel: [    4.213177] PM: Looking for hibernation image.
Dec 14 00:41:38 host kernel: [    4.231179] PM: Looking for hibernation image.
Dec 14 00:54:53 host kernel: [    4.219918] PM: Looking for hibernation image.
Dec 14 01:05:22 host kernel: [    4.213743] PM: Looking for hibernation image.
```

and this output from dmesg

```
[    4.213743] PM: Looking for hibernation image.
```

by the way this laptop has 16GB of ram and I have 32GB swap, just to make sure. I've read that 32GB is overkill but I just had to test it out.

What else can I do to sort this thing out and get hibernate to work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

### Setting hybernation file

as mentioned on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/832498/pm-hibernation-image-not-present-or-could-not-be-loaded/984260) post, setting the hybernation file could help...

1. Find uuid of your swap partition. Suppose the partition is sdb3, then

   ```
   $ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | grep sdb3
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 окт.   9 08:59 1dd7e123-1f82-45f0-a202-0ff3ea6f081a -> ../../sdb3
   ```
2. Open `/etc/default/grub`, and find the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="`. Add there between the quotes `resume=/dev/disk/by-uuid/your-swap-uuid`. As an example:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/disk/by-uuid/1dd7e123-1f82-45f0-a202-0ff3ea6f081a"
   ```
3. Run as a root `update-grub`

### bios settings

Another problem I had were some bios settings. I reloaded the **bios defaults** and it finally worked

Comment: At least as of Ubuntu 18.04 (and possibly also whatever upstream Debian version that corresponds to) it seems to be *absolutely essential* to set the `resume` parameter by UUID. Hopefully this saves someone else hours of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the image location in your `/etc/default/grub` by pathing it like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=/dev/sda4"
```